# TranslateAnimation like a curve way in android

Tags: android, animation

How can I create animation for moving a image like a curve from top to bottom? Here I used TranslateAnimation for this, 
But it will move the image from top to bottom depends on the x, y co-ordinates. But, I want to move the image like a curve.
But in my code, it moves like a line.

```
public class ImageMoveActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TranslateAnimation transform;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView im1,im2,im3;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        transform = new TranslateAnimation(0, 150, 0, 300);
        //transform = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 20, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 50, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
        //im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        im2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        im3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textview);


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this
                .getResources(), R.drawable.xxl);
        /* set other image top of the first icon */
        Bitmap bitmapStar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this
                .getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
//        Bitmap bmOverlay1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapStar.getWidth(),
//              bitmapStar.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        //Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmOverlay1);
        canvas.drawARGB(0x00, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        //canvas1.drawARGB(0x00, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapStar, 0, 0, null);

        BitmapDrawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmOverlay);
        //BitmapDrawable dr1 = new BitmapDrawable(bmOverlay1);
        dr.setBounds(10, 30, 10, 30);
        //dr1.setBounds(10, 30, 10, 30);

        im1.setImageDrawable(dr);
        //im3.setImageDrawable(dr1);

//im1.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.xxl);
        im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                start();
                hide();
            }
            private void start() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                im1.startAnimation(transform);
                transform.setDuration(1000);
                //transform.setFillAfter(true);
            }
            private void hide() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                im1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });


    }
}
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

TranslateAnimation can move Views from one point to another in a straight line. As far as I know you can't give any other path to it. Try using custom views and canvas for the the this, where you can pass x and y coordinates while drawing and invalidating the view. You need to override the following method while extending the View class. The changeCoordinate() method here can change the x,y coordinates in a curve.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,x,y,null);
  changeCoordinate();
  invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a series of translate animation from one point to another on curve and apply the animation to views.

Like if we have an imageView which is to be animated, and a1, and a2 are animations to be applied:

```
   imgView.clearAnimation();
    imgView.startAnimation(a1);

  imgView.clearAnimation();
    imgView.startAnimation(a2);
```